# WYSIWYG Visual Designer Javascript Library

Tags: javascript, html-editor, jquery, wysiwyg

I am looking for a Javascript library that provides widget editting features such as:

- Draggable Widgets (textbox, imagebox, link)
- Scale Widgets by clicking one of the four corners of the widget
- Rotate Widget by clicking a rotation icon on the widget

What is the term for this functionality? WYSIWYG Editor doesn't quite sum up this or maybe it does? This kind of editting feature is standard on desktop applications but not very common in web applications. In desktop, the functionality I am referring to is the Visual Studio Application Designer, Photoshop text editting, etc.

Below is an example of the kind of functionality I am looking for in a javascript library:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would check out [Pixie - Image Editor](http://codecanyon.net/item/pixie-image-editor/10721475). Pixie is a photo editing & manipulation application. It is perfect for integration into other projects or personal and other use. Unlike other similar products it is built with html5 and javascript and not outdated technologies like flash. This makes Pixie future-proof, allows for much better performance and cross-device compatibility.

To search for this, I used the search phrase: "javascript image layers editor"

[image: Pixie]

Comment: Tom, do you think that the OP doesn't know how to Google?  We strongly prefer answerers to have actually used the software that they recommend, and to explain how it addresses the question. Please read  [ask].

Comment: @Mawg I agree with using the software before you answer a question but I actually did use it, http://pixie.vebto.com/

Comment: Also, the OP did ask, "What is the term for this functionality?" So I gave him the phrase I used to search for this software

Comment: Please accept my apologies (and some upvotes). I can be somewhat grumpy on Monday mornings :-/   and you make two good points in your comments.

Comment: @Mawg Don't be, we all are on Monday:)

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports dragging and dropping elements from a palette. You can try this out in the online sample [sample](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/dashboard/diagrambuilder/default.html).

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense).

[image: screenshot]

Note: I work for Syncfusion